# Binding error on multibinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

For the following xaml

```
<Window x:Class="StaticResourceBinding.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:staticResourceBinding="clr-namespace:StaticResourceBinding"        
    x:Name="Me" >    
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <staticResourceBinding:MultiConverter x:Key="MultiConverter" ></staticResourceBinding:MultiConverter>                        
    </Grid.Resources>        

    <ContentControl>
        <ContentControl.Content>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiConverter}">
                <Binding Source="SomeText"></Binding>                    
                <Binding>
                    <Binding.Source>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SecondText, ElementName=Me}" ></TextBlock>
                    </Binding.Source>
                </Binding>                                        
            </MultiBinding>
        </ContentControl.Content>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

I get this error.

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=Me'. BindingExpression:Path=SecondText; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

The converter just picks the first value of the multi-binding.

When I set the binding that binds to the "SecondText" property first no binding exception is thrown.

My naive assumption would be that the TextBlock control is created but put outside of the visual tree causing it not the find the "Me"-element up the tree.

Is this correct? And how can I prevent this binding exception.

Needless to say I've kept this example simple (and stupid) for clarity.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Why did you put a TextBlock inside a BindingSource? Why not just specify SecondText as Path for binding? Where is SomeText located?

Comment: The full story goes: I want a main user control with a property that can be set(which in it's turn is a usercontrol), lets call it backgroundControl. If this property is null, I want to use a default user control which uses another property on the main user control which defines how the default control looks. Everything works except that I get the stated exception when backgroundControl is set (not null). The binding exception happens on the binding of the default control.

Answer (score 0):

I would say try adding the second text box outside the binding in your XAML, then bind to the text property.

```
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiConverter}">
            <Binding ElementName="FirstText" Path="Text"/>
            <Binding ElementName="SecondText" Path="Text"/>
        </MultiBinding>
```

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for. Please see my comment on the question.